# Store a json response in an array in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp, post

I'm sending a json post response with this in body {"firstname":"abcrehd","lastname":"sdfsdf"}
How do I declare an array in the controller and save the json response in the array, and then display the array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTM [Accessing Querystring parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters).

`$this->request->query`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer:

```
$data=$this->request->input('json_decode');
pr($data);
```

This will save incoming data as an array in $data and print the array. :)